# Saving png stream to bitmap in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, bitmap

I have a Memory stream in png format and want to save it to a Bitmap object so that I can extract the pixels. I am using .net 2.0 and cannot use a higher version due to certain restrictions. Can you please help me out ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the System.Drawing.Bitmap object?

It has a constructor of `public Bitmap(Stream stream)`

you can then do what you like with the bitmap before calling `Save`